# Doctrine DQL query to Mysql query syntax error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-query

I am having a hard time finding out why this Doctrine dql query is not working in my symfony application.

Mysql query is this:

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN c_email IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) * 100.00) / COUNT(c_number) AS percentage
FROM 
    distinct_customers;
```

My Symfony doctrine php code is this

```
   public function invalidEmails()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT (count(case  when  ds.c_email IS NOT null then 1 end))*100/count(ds.c_number) as percentage FROM App\Entity\DistinctCustomers ds');
        return $qb->getResult();
    }
```

But I get an error each time

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 69: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ELSE, got 'end'`

has someone ran into this in the past?

Comment: Try `case when c_email IS not NULL then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: @Myonara Hi, I did try that but it skips over the first case and returns this

`array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["percentage"]=> string(8) "100.0000" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` block needs an `ELSE` condition.

In addition, it looks like you're trying to count the cases where email is not null, but instead of using the `COUNT` function (which would count `nulls` and `zeroes` as well as `1`'s) you need to use the `SUM` function.

Try this:

```
SELECT(
    SUM(
        CASE
        WHEN ds.c_email IS NOT null
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
    )
)*100/COUNT(ds.c_number) AS percentage
FROM App\Entity\DistinctCustomers ds
```